# What is difference between compensate and recompense?

Tags: vocabulary

As far as I know from dictionary that both words compensate and recompense are same in meaning .But are those actually same or is there any precise difference?

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not the same, although in some cases they may be interchangeable.

If you recompense something, you pay back expenses that have been incurred. So I paid for something, and you pay me back for it. This *is* a for of compensation!

To compensate for something (notice also the difference in use!), you may recompense expenses. But there are many other options.

Someone may compensate for a lack of knowledge with a great ability to look things up.
I may compensate for your expenses by giving you time off.